# SwiftUI: Overlay an SKScene over an SCNScene

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, scenekit

Setup:

- For displaying 3D elements Scenekit is used. For 2D elements Spritekit.
- SceneView() is used to display a scene.
- An SCNScene and an SCNNode for the camera are given.

Goal:

Now I want to put a 2D overlay over the SCNScene. Previously this could be achieved using the overlaySKScene property of the SCNView. But now that in SwiftUI only the scene and camera are given I wonder how this can be achieved.

Thanks already in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The SpriteKit overlay is not supported by `SceneView` in iOS 14.

Comment: where did you find this information ? I encountered it some time ago and had to change my overlay.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `SpriteKit` scene layered on top of an `SCNScene`, you can do it with SwiftUI, like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var 2dscene = MyScene()
    @State private var 3dScene = SCNScene(named: "MyFile")

    var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           SceneView(scene: 3dScene)
           SpriteView(scene: 2dscene)
       }
    }
}
```